# List the child nodes in tree when parent expanded

Tags: java, mysql, tree, treeview

I have a problem in implementing the tree structure of OID. when I click the parent , i need to display only child details, not the sub child of a child.
i.e., i need not display an OID which contains a "." (dot).

For example, if my OID structure is private.MIB.sample.first
private.MIB.sample.second and so on.

when I click on MIB, it should display only "sample" not first and second.

first and second is to be displayed when I click sample.
How can I implement this in java.
My datyabase is MySQL. The code which I tried is given below

```
        FilteredRowSet rs = new FilteredRowSetImpl();

        // for Other Types Like OBJECT-TYPE, Object_IDENTIFIER
        rs = new FilteredRowSetImpl();
        rs.setCommand("Select * from MIBNODEDETAILS where " + "mn_OID like '" + OID
                + ".%' order by mn_NodeType, mn_OID");
        rs.setUrl(Constants.DB_CONNECTION_URL);
        rs.setFilter(new MibRowFilter(1, expString));
        rs.execute();

        rs.absolute(1);
        rs.beforeFirst();
```

I guess the change is to be made in the setCommand argument.

How can I do this?

Structure of mobnodedetails table

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| mn_OID             | mn_name           | mn_nodetype |
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| 1                  | iso               |           0 |
| 1.3                | org               |           1 |
| 1.3.6              | dod               |           1 |
| 1.3.6.1            | internet          |           1 |
| 1.3.6.1.1          | directory         |           1 |
| 1.3.6.1.2          | mgmt              |           1 |
| 1.3.6.1.2.1        | mib-2             |           0 |
| 1.3.6.1.2.1.1      | system            |           1 |
| 1.3.6.1.2.1.10     | transmission      |           1 |
```

Comment: You could have 2 approaches: 1) Connecting to the database to get the children of the selected node every time a node is selected, 2) Get all the data in a single query, then build the tree programmatically.

Comment: can you pls explain your table structure?

Comment: Table contains mn_OID(integer), mn_Nodetype(integer), mn_nodeName(string)

Comment: @Gapchoos I got your requirement but how this parent child relation is stored in database my question is this.

Comment: @Gapchoos check my answer and let me know whether it is same as you want or different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function given below dispalys the tree as required.

```
public void populateMibValues()
{

    final DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) this.m_mibTree.getModel();
    model.setRoot(null);

    this.rootNode.removeAllChildren();
    final String query_MibNodeDetailsSelect = "Select * from MIBNODEDETAILS where LENGTH(mn_oid)<=9 "
            + " and mn_OID<='1.3.6.1.4.1' order by mn_OID"; // only

    this.innerNodeNames.clear();
    this.innerNodes.clear();
    this.innerNodesOid = null;

    try {
        final ResultSet deviceRS = Application.getDBHandler().executeQuery(query_MibNodeDetailsSelect, null);// inner
        // nodes

        while (deviceRS.next()) {
            final mibNode mb = new mibNode(deviceRS.getString("mn_OID").toString(), deviceRS.getString("mn_name")
                    .toString());
            mb.m_Type = Integer.parseInt(deviceRS.getString("mn_nodetype").toString());
            createMibTree(mb);
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        Application.showErrorInConsole(e);
        NmsLogger.writeErrorLog("ERROR creating MIB tree failed", e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
  SELECT *
    FROM mibnodedetails
   WHERE mn_oid LIKE "+mn_OID+"%
    AND LENGTH ("+mn_OID+") + 2 = LENGTH (mn_oid)
ORDER BY mn_nodetype, mn_oid
```

So if you pass mm_OID as `1.3.6.1 (|1.3.6.1 |internet |1 |)`

You will get following result:

```
| 1.3.6.1.1          | directory         |           1 |
| 1.3.6.1.2          | mgmt              |           1 |
```

**[Working Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8780d/2)**

**PS:** This will not work for child more than 9 as we are using length + 2

Comment: Sorry this doesnt give the result. I dont wanna get the parent. instead display only the direct child, not the sub child. In this case, when I click on "dod" display only the "directory" and not the management and other nodes.

Comment: @Gapchoos clicking on "dod" it should only display "internet".

Comment: @Gapchoos please give me input and output based on your data in the question so I can help you.